# Parentheses around part of Tikz matrix

Tags: tikz-pgf, matrices

Given the following matrix, how can I change the parentheses to enclose only the numbers of the matrix, like the ones that I scribbled in the picture below?

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\matrix(m) [matrix of math nodes, 
         left delimiter=(,right delimiter={)}, nodes={minimum size=1cm, outer sep=0pt, text height=1.5ex, text depth=.25ex}]
{
\phantom{} & I & II & III & IV \\
A & 15 & 3 & 30 & 20 \\
B & 20 & 2 & 20 & 30\\
C & 40 & 20 & 10 & 40 \\
D & 5 & 30 & 40 & 40 \\
};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `left delimeter` and `right delimeter` option can be given to a any node that has the standard anchors. Therefore you can enclose any tikz node with delimiters.

For example, you can define a node that fit the submatrix that you want with the fit library:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    add paren/.style={
      left delimiter={(},
      right delimiter={)}, 
    }
  ]

  \matrix(m) [matrix of math nodes, 
    add paren,
    nodes={minimum size=1cm, outer sep=0pt, text height=1.5ex, text depth=.25ex}
  ]
  {
      & I  & II & III & IV \\
    A & 15 & 3  & 30  & 20 \\
    B & 20 & 2  & 20  & 30 \\
    C & 40 & 20 & 10  & 40 \\
    D & 5  & 30 & 40  & 40 \\
  };

  \node[fit=(m-3-3) (m-5-5), add paren] (submatrix) {};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result is not entirely satisfactory:

[image]

You can fix it with a negative inner sep in sumbmatrix node:

```
\node[fit=(m-3-3) (m-5-5), add paren, inner xsep=-1ex] (submatrix) {};
```

[image]

or by using different options in the matrix definition:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    add paren/.style={
      left delimiter={(},
      right delimiter={)}, 
    }
  ]

  \matrix(m) [matrix of math nodes, 
    add paren,
    column sep={1cm,between origins},
    row sep={1cm,between origins},
  ]
  {
      & I  & II & III & IV \\
    A & 15 & 3  & 30  & 20 \\
    B & 20 & 2  & 20  & 30 \\
    C & 40 & 20 & 10  & 40 \\
    D & 5  & 30 & 40  & 40 \\
  };

  \node[fit=(m-3-3) (m-5-5), add paren, inner sep=0pt] (submatrix) {};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's a great solution and easy to implement.

Answer (score 6):

Since you already used Ti*k*Z to implement your matrix, here's a solution using `nicematrix` package (which loads and uses Ti*k*Z):

[image: matrix inside matrix]

```
\documentclass[border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,nicematrix}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}

$\begin{pNiceMatrix}[columns-width = 20pt,margin=5pt,cell-space-limits = 10pt]
    \phantom{} & I & II & III & IV \\
    A & 15 & 3 & 30 & 20 \\
    B & 20 & 2 & 20 & 30\\
    C & 40 & 20 & 10 & 40 \\
    D & 5 & 30 & 40 & 40
    \CodeAfter\SubMatrix({2-2}{5-5})
\end{pNiceMatrix}$

\end{document}
```

Note that you may have to compile at least twice to see the final result (one for defining nodes, and another one to draw accordingly).

Comment: Great for general use of Latex, however in my case I wanted tikz to be able to draw some figures.

Comment: No problem, the other solution is of great use and with some nice exlplanations. But note that `nicematrix` is Ti*k*Z based and so allows you to draw anything, since all figures are nested into nodes named (1-1) to (n-n).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!